# Should.I use listview or listactivity

Tags: java, android, listview

I have say 3 images in a view and want to display a list upon selecting any of the images.  Upon selecting an image a list shows up adjacent to the image that was selected.  Only one list can show at a time, so if a list is visible next to one image and another  image is selected a new list is built next to the selected image and the existing list disappears.

The lists are built using arrays.

Should I use listview or listactivity.  Or might there be a better approach to doing this.

Thanks,

Comment: use recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

you can use Recyclerview List for your mentioned problem

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, according to me, is to make the layout as you want with the images and with listviews and put initially visibility gone on the lists. When a image is clicked make that list visible (`setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`)  and the other ones gone (`setVisibility(View.GONE)`).

This is the most straightforward solution.